# Designing microservices in practice

Tags: microservices

Yet another question on how to or how not to split up a microservice :-D

The scenario:
What do we need?
Sending emails at different points of time within the work flow of an ecommerce order process. These mails will be containing order information.

What do we have?

1 x  persistence service which retrieves order information

Several  services which subscribe to order events and processes the relevant use case (e.g. Confirmation, delivery, invoice)

1 x service which can be triggered to send a mail

What's the next step?
Designing the architectural component which transforms the order information so they will fit the data structure of the email rendering service.

The current options are

## 1 having each processing service transform already existing order information for the mail template and send them to the mail rendering service.

## 2 have each processing service call a new service which would aggregate and transform the order information and call the mail rendering service.

Currently we're not sure yet if the data structures for the mail templates will be mostly common or if there will be differences.

So what do you think of these options in terms of cohesion, coupling and separation of concerns?
Do you need any more information?  Any constructive thoughts are welcome!

Comment: `2 have each processing service call a new service which would aggregate and transform the order information and call the mail rendering service.` - why would one introduce another microservice?

Comment: What are your bounded contexts? That's how I'd begin; taking a look at those and using that to try an initial split. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Answer (score 0):

Your software architecture should reflect your organizational structure, see [Conway's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law)

1. Do you have multiple teams, and you want to minimize dependencies between the teams.
2. Are "services" large and complex enough to justify them being separated into modules?
3. Does the size of the product justify having advanced devops in place to orchestrate the microservices?
4. Do you need the flexibility in terms of deployment and replaceability of individual "services"?

If you can answer yes to most of these questions, it would make sense to go for microservices. Otherwise, you are just making your life complicated.

Frankly, microservices require a lot of coordination overhead which makes sense only if the product is large enough. Most (small) projects are just fine with monolithic and MVC architecture.

Comment: I don't know if that's a requirement that the architecture reflect conway's law; only that that's what tends to happen.  Conway's law is a reflection on what seems to be, not what is required to be.

Comment: Agree with @GeorgeStocker. Conway's law is not a "to be desired result" as much as an observation, that over period of time, softwares implemented tend to mimic organizational hierarchy. In light of those observations, when implementing cloud transformation, it is advocated to use flat cross-functional team aka the two pizza team.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I propose to proceed man, it's how one of my project's architecture does all SMTP related stuff.

[image]

1. API receives an HTTP request
2. It persists data needed to the database.
3. It offloads the long-running and memory intensive processes to mail builder.
4. Optional, mail builder builds attachment files (XLSX, PDF, etc)
5. Mail builder uploads to File Server
6. Mail builder offloads generic SMTP sending to SMTP service.

I suggested this format because it allows you to scale the instance of each piece (Mail builder will have tons of instances) depending on bottlenecks in your processing pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have asked this question in `microservices`, I am assuming you are asking the question in reference to cloud native patterns.

I suggest you start with looking at microservices pattern. An excellent site for the patterns is https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html.

Your question does not have the necessary details to provide an educated advice on what patterns are suitable and what are not. So, I suggest you look at these few patterns...
https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html
https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html

Also take a look at event sourcing pattern
https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html

Hope this helps.